# AutoLayout constraints issues on IBOutlet label but not programmatically created label

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, ios8

I have two UITableViews (in different VCs), each with their own cell, DynamicCell and MyTableViewCell.

DynamicCell creates a UILabel *programmatically* and then adds constraints (also programmatically). DynamicCell works perfectly fine, and uses iOS 8's self-sizing feature of UITableViewCells. The code is exactly the same as in this year's WWDC session *What's New in Table & Collection Views* (Session 226, demo starts ~12:30). The label & constraints creation is all done in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

MyTableViewCell on the other hand has an IBOutlet to the UILabel in storyboards. But I add the *exact same* constraints programmatically in `awakeFromNib`.

But this cell does not act anything like the DynamicCell and I'd appreciate if someone could tell me why. I also get spammed with AutoLayout constraints issues in the console for MyTableViewCell. [Here's the project.](http://cl.ly/0m3i2l2f0m2I) (Requires Xcode 6)

The reason I'm not adding constraints for MyTableViewCell in the storyboard is because I don't seem to be able to set constraints from the contentView of the cell to the any of the label's *baselines* using IB even though the engineer in the session video does say that he could have created the programmatically created constraints in IB.